# Is there a way to add parent class to property if child exists in less

Tags: less

I have a parent div and child div. I need to apply background color to parent only if the child class is presents.

```
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    <div class="morechild">
  <div>
```

For example only if "child" class exists add background color to "parent"

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `:has()` ?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.child,
.morechild,
.parent {
  margin: 5px 20px;
}

.parent {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: #00000050;
}

.morechild {
  color: white;
  background-color: #00000090;
}

.parent:has(.child) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="morechild">morechild</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="morechild">morechild</div>
</div>
```